# Validate oAuth2.0 Token in WSO2

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, salesforce, wso2

Here is our scenario:
- Mr.X uses application provided by Company A
- Company A wants to call a REST service hosted at Company B on behalf of Mr.X
- Company B wants to secure the REST service using oAuth2.0 
- Company B uses Salesforce as system of record for identities. Mr.X has an account defined in Salesforce.

We are Company B. Can WSO2 handle such a scenario ? If so, what is the easiest way to handle such scenario ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Just to clarify your problem, you are Company B which has set of REST services. You need to secure those APIs with oAuth2.0. Mr X belongs to company B and Mr Xs identity inside Company Bs sales force system. Now Company A wants to call a REST service hosted at Company B on behalf of Mr.X

Comment: Then Mr X has to provide his credentials to Company A will it be ok with you

Comment: Hi There is a way you can implement this solution. Company B can secure their REST services by using WSO2 APIM. Whatever your sales force identity records point as user store to APIM. Now company As application can use authorization code grant type to get access token and invoke oauth protected APIs in company B. During authorize request Mr X provide his credentials to authorization server running on company B but not for the application provided by company A so he is safe.